# Is it necessary to ANALYZE a table after an index has been created?

Tags: postgresql, index, vacuum

In my transaction, I am creating a temporary table:

```
create temporary table x on commit drop as
select ...
```

I also add an index on that table:

```
create index on x(some_column);
```

Is it now necessary to run `analyze` on that table? Or do I only need to analyze the table for updates/deletes **after** index creation?

In other words, my question is: does the creation of an index already imply an `analyze` execution?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If the index is just on **simple columns** like in your case, it is **not necessary to `ANALYZE`** the table after you create the index.
That is because statistics on the value distribution of the table columns are always collected, no matter if there is an index on the column or not.

However, if you are **indexing an expression** like `upper(some_column)` or `(CAST(some_column AS date))`, **you should run `ANALYZE`** after creating the index.
PostgreSQL will then also collect statistics on the value distribution of the indexed expression. This happens automatically whenever autoanalyze runs, but it is a good idea to do it manually right after creating the index so you have good statistics right away.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense to me. Does this knowledge hold for any kind of index type (BTREE, GIN, GIST, ...)? In my specific case, I have a GIST index on `(city_identifier, period)` (of which `period` is a `tstzrange`). Since both are just columns, the `analyze` is not needed here as well?

Comment: This is also true for GIN and GiST indexes. I am not sure if it holds for all index access methods.

Comment: Regarding the access methods, it is `=` for `city_identifier` and `&&` for `period` in my specific case.

Comment: An *index access method* is something like GIN or GiST. `&&` is an operator. Try it yourself and see if you find statistics in `pg_stats`. But yes, it is like I wrote in my answer.

Comment: There must be other conditions to make it work without `ANALYZE`, see my alternative answer.

Answer (score 1):

I just added an index to a `date` column:

```
CREATE INDEX ON t (col);
```

I ran a query like

```
SELECT id
FROM t
WHERE col <= '2021-12-20'
AND col >= '2021-12-20'
```

The index was not used until I ran `ANALYZE t`.

This was on Postgres 12.7.

Comment: That seems unrelated. You probably didn't insert enough rows to trigger autoanalyze, or you didn't give it enough time to complete.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Not sure what you mean. The table is old and already contains a million rows or so. I tried the query immediately after the `CREATE INDEX`. From your answer I expected it to pick up the index right after it was created, but apparently an `ANALYZE` was necessary in my case.

Comment: No, that is not how PostgreSQL works. Statistics on columns are collected whether an index exists or not, and the index is used as soon as it is created. Your table statistics must have been off for reasons that can probably no longer be figured out.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Oh, I didn't consider the possibility that my column statistics already were off and the `ANALYZE` fixed that independently of the index.  Not sure why though.

Comment: There might be something to this. We found PG wasn't using a new index that it should use. The `last_autoanalyze` for the table was 3 days prior. We then ran a manual analyze, and it started using the new index. This table has over a year of data, so only roughly 1% of the data was new since the previous autoanalyze, and nothing is special about it compared to the other 99%. The index is a btree index on `column_a ASC, column_b DESC`. This behavior is surprising to me too and I'm searching for answers.

Comment: @Aurast Your index contains more than one column, so it makes sense that an ANALYZE was needed.

Comment: Thanks @AndreKR so that's the key? Would you happen to know any documentation about that? I tried searching the docs but didn't find any info.

Comment: @Aurast You can examine the statistics as described [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/planner-stats.html).

Answer (score 0):

This thread is old but the existing answer doesn't look right.

As per https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html

"The autovacuum daemon cannot access and therefore cannot vacuum or analyze temporary tables. For this reason, appropriate vacuum and analyze operations should be performed via session SQL commands. For example, if a temporary table is going to be used in complex queries, it is wise to run ANALYZE on the temporary table after it is populated."