# Do I need to ANALYZE table after DROP INDEX?

Tags: postgresql, index

In our postgres db we historically have many similar indexes (e.g. `is_deleted` boolean) that have quite bad selectivity value. Worse than that, sometimes query planner *breaks* and postgres starts to use some of them instead of much more efficient indexes so we need to call `ANALYZE` manually to fix performance, so we decided to delete most of them.

Do we need to call `ANALYZE` for each table after deleting index?

According to the answer in [Is it necessary to ANALYZE a table after an index has been created?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/241257/is-it-necessary-to-analyze-a-table-after-an-index-has-been-created) postgres collects stats about actual values in table (for simple indexes) without index-related info but I couldn't find proof in docs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it's not necessary. Statistics on the main table are not affected by indexes at all.

One thing to observe: expression indexes introduce new "derived" columns, and Postgres gathers separate statistics for those. Removing such indexes also removes the special statistics - which may lead to different query plans, beyond the fact that the index is gone.

Since you mention indexes on `boolean` columns: those hardly ever make sense and it's a good idea to remove those. boolean column typically only make sense as condition in a partial index. There is an [example in the manual.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/indexes-partial.html#INDEXES-PARTIAL-EX3)